# Laravel 8 Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am running `php artisan cache:clear` to clear the cache in Godaddy shared hosting through SSH.

My other `artisan` commands working but  `php artisan cache:clear` not.

I am getting following error :

```
Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions.
```

Comment: make sure `bootstrap/cache` folder have correct permission  `read/write`

Comment: Make sure that your user has correct permissions on `storage/cache` folder. If not take a look on this question and give correct permissions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this issue by deleting all files in `bootstrap/cache.` Then, run the following commands.

```
php artisan cache:clear

composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 1):

The user that executes `php artisan cache:clear` must have write permissions on the following directories and content recursively.

```
booststrap/cache/*
storage/*
```

To check files that user does not have write permission for

```sh
find booststrap/cache storage -not -perm -u=w
```

Finally fix permissions:

```sh
chmod -R u+w bootstrap/cache storage
```

Comment: thank you! not having permission on ALL directories in those folders was what was causing the problems for me, even if the problematic folder was not directly related to cache

Answer (score 0):

You can also user Artisan facade to clear cache in live server/production.

```
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```